# Use user's input as loop counter

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos

First of all, yes, I know it's 21st century, but I'm learning old assembler with DosBox and NASM in my college. I have to get number from input and print as many asterisks (`*`) as user defined. For example:

```
Enter the number (1-9): 5
*****
```

Pretty simple, right? But I don't know how to use readed value as counter. My current code:

```
org     100h

mov dx, number_txt
mov ah, 9
int 0x21

mov dx, buffer
mov ah, 0Ah        
int 0x21                    ; read number

mov dx, br
mov ah, 9
int 0x21                ; enter

mov dx, asterysk            ; will write "*"
mov ah, 9

mov cx, buffertxt           ; HERE IS THE PROBLEM
myloop:
    int 0x21            ; write *
loop myloop

mov ax, 0x4C00
int 0x21                ; end

number_txt: db "Enter the number (1-9): $"
br: db 0Ah,0Dh,"$"
asterysk: db "*$"
buffer: db 5,0
buffertxt: times 5 db "$"
```

Currently I'm getting 4.5 lines of `*`, no matter what number I write. I know I have to convert `buffertxt` to int/hex to use as counter in `cx`, but I have no idea how.

I've read a lot in Google and here, but I didn't find answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
mov cx, buffertxt           ; HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

should be changed to:

```
mov cl, [buffertxt]     ; Read the first character of the user input
sub cl,'0'              ; Convert from '0'..'9' to 0..9
xor ch,ch               ; Clear the upper half of CX (the LOOP instruction
                        ; uses all of CX as the counter)
```

---

By the way, you can use [`INT 21H / AH=2`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) to print a single character, instead of passing a single-character string to `INT 21H / AH=9`.

Comment: Works great, thank you. I tried something similiar with sub, but I didn't know what to do with ch.